# Need help rendering 'ggplotly()' object in Quarto

Tags: r, rstudio, spatial, quarto, ggplotly

I want to embed an interactive map I made in plotly to an RMarkdown document in Quarto. I have it saved under this path "figures/community_area_shootings_plotly.html".

I tried using

````
```{quarto_include: src="figures/community_area_shootings_plotly.html"}
````

and

````
```{embed: src="figures/community_areas_shootings_plotly.html"}
````

Neither worked. What is the best way to embed it if it is already saved as an HTML. Do I need to put it in a code chunk or directly in the content of the Quarto doc?

Answer (score 0):

Like you, I have tried many times to embed a HTML document inside an R Markdown or Quarto document, but without success. However, I found a hack, which involves the following steps:

1. In your Quarto/RMD document, include a placeholder for where you want to include your interactive plotly visualization. Then render the document as a `html_output`.
2. Next, host your interactive plotly visualization as a website using either github pages or [netlify](https://www.netlify.com/).
3. Open the Quarto/RMD document with a HTML editor like VSCode or Notepad++, then embed the hosted plotly visualization as an `<iframe>` like this where you have your placeholder and save:

`<iframe src="https://ifeanyi55.github.io/plotly-contour-plot/" frameborder="0" width="850" height="450"></iframe>`

4. Open the webpage and you should see your interactive plotly visualization rendered on the webpage.

[image]

I hope this helps!